# Adding 3rd party unmanaged DLLs to a SharpDX WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx

The company I work has a subsidiary company that makes several OEM video capture cards. The card I am using has 2 channels of HD video 1920 x 1080 @ 30 FPS. Using their API and example I would like to access their DLL into a SharpDX WPF application. I have loaded SharpDX 2.6 and gone through the demos. I see how to use a texture which is where I would like to put the frames.

What I don't see is how to link in two DLLs from them and make the calls to their unmanaged code. Is this similar to incorporating other unmanaged code into a managed application. I have seen this done by delaring an IDisposable unsafe class, copying struct's from the unmanaged header file and labeling them unsafe then declaring the API functions in the following manner:

```
const string dllname = "dvsoemnvdbg.dll";
const CallingConvention convention = CallingConvention.Cdecl;
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = convention, PreserveSig = true)]
static extern SV_ERROR sv_close(sv_handle* sv);
```

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but there is a SharpDX nuget package available: http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=sharpdx

Comment: David, Thanks! I apologize I was not more clear. In trying to be brief I lost clarity.